# An iPhone app to play audio in (from microphone) over speakers (or headphones)

Tags: audio, iphone-app, accessibility

My Father is deaf and uses a hearing loop around his neck to pick up audio. However, this needs a large, bulky box to amplify the sound.

He bought a [3.5mm jack to Headphone + Microphone splitter](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B00JSS8NR2/ref=asc_df_B00JSS8NR253967369/?tag=googshopuk-21&creative=22146&creativeASIN=B00JSS8NR2&linkCode=df0&hvadid=214453842616&hvpos=1o1&hvnetw=g&hvrand=14655437923647002319&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9050381&hvtargid=pla-420169752430) (link is as an example, not as an advert) which works with the iPhone; we tested by recording then playing an audio file.

However, we need an app that will play audio in over the speakers / headphones out - in real time, [a little like this in Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/22347/windows-how-can-i-redirect-sound-coming-in-from-the-mic-to-the-speakers-output).

We found a few apps, but they all seem to record and *then* play it back. Is there one that will do this?

We would like a free app (of course) but will happily pay a little if we know it will work. This is an iPhone 4 which is fully updated.